# Makefile - How to execute mkdir in if-endif conditionally?

Tags: makefile

I'm a beginner to makefile domain. I need to check variable and determine if we need to create a folder.

While I run make command; the terminal pops up error message as below:

```
Makefile:6: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.
```

Could anyone please help to give me some comments?

Thanks

```
## Pass OUTPUTDIR from parent makefile
OUTPUTDIR          ?=

ifeq ($(OUTPUTDIR),)
    OUTPUTDIR := $(CURDIR)/tmp
        mkdir -p $(OUTPUTDIR)
endif
```

## Update

I try to create a tmp folder under currecnt directory if OUTPUTDIR doesn't contain any string; but it failed. Because I don't see tmp folder is created. Seems ifeq ($(OUTPUTDIR),) is incorrect statement; any suggestion here?

Thanks

```
.PHONY: all

CP := /bin/cp

## Pass OUTPUTDIR from parent makefile
OUTPUTDIR          ?=

ifeq ($(OUTPUTDIR),)
    OUTPUTDIR := $(CURDIR)/tmp
target:    
        mkdir -p $(OUTPUTDIR)
endif

all:
        $(CP) -f test.txt $(OUTPUTDIR)/test.txt
```

Comment: Commands (recipes) like the `mkdir` line have to be associated with a target rule (`target:`) — and yours is not, just like the error message says.

Comment: Ok, I use below statements; but still can't create tmp folder under current directory.
Looks like ifeq ($(OUTPUTDIR),) have problem.

Could you give me some comments?

Thanks


.PHONY: all

CP := /bin/cp

## Pass OUTPUTDIR from parent makefile
OUTPUTDIR          ?=

ifeq ($(OUTPUTDIR),)
    OUTPUTDIR := $(CURDIR)/tmp
target:    
        mkdir -p $(OUTPUTDIR)
endif

all:
        $(CP) -f test.txt $(OUTPUTDIR)/test.txt

Comment: Don't undo people’s efforts to format your question.

Answer (score 0):

The `-p` option of `mkdir` is helpful here because if the directory already exists `mkdir -p` does not raise an error.

If you use GNU make you can declare the directory as an [order-only prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) of your final target (to understand why declaring it as a regular prerequisite is wrong see [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types)):

```
OUTPUTDIR ?= $(CURDIR)/tmp

.PHONY: all

all: $(OUTPUTDIR)/test.txt

$(OUTPUTDIR)/test.txt: test.txt | $(OUTPUTDIR)
    cp -f '$<' '$@'

$(OUTPUTDIR):
    mkdir -p '$@'
```

A simpler solution consists in using the `shell` GNU make function to systematically create the directory, but this is less elegant:

```
OUTPUTDIR ?= $(CURDIR)/tmp
DUMMY := $(shell mkdir -p '$(OUTPUTDIR)')
```

If you don't use GNU make simply create the directory in the recipe of your final target:

```
OUTPUTDIR ?= $(CURDIR)/tmp

.PHONY: all

all: $(OUTPUTDIR)/test.txt

$(OUTPUTDIR)/test.txt: test.txt
    mkdir -p '$(@D)'
    cp -f '$<' '$@'
```

Note that `OUTPUTDIR ?= $(CURDIR)/tmp` assigns `OUTPUTDIR` only if it has not been already assigned, which makes your `ifeq` test useless (unless it is first assigned the empty string).